# How to filter array to get only the object and not array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, functional-programming

I'm not even sure what to search for for this question. What I really want is I have an array of objects  like this

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#423 (4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "Blah"
    ["full_name"]=>
    string(10) "/Blah"
    ["id"]=>
    string(32) "BlahBlah"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(32) "BlahBlah"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#422 (4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Blah1"
    ["full_name"]=>
    string(9) "Blah2"
    ["id"]=>
    string(32) "BlahBlah2"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    NULL
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#421 (4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "Blah3"
    ["full_name"]=>
    string(11) "Blah3"
    ["id"]=>
    string(32) "BlahBlah3"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    string(32) "BlahBlahBlah3"
  }
}
```

I want to filter to just the object that I want so what I did was

```
   $found_label = array_filter($labels, function($obj) use($label) {
       return $obj->name === $label;
   });
```

But then the results I got is this

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#422 (4) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "Blah1"
    ["full_name"]=>
    string(9) "Blah1"
    ["id"]=>
    string(32) "BlahBlah2"
    ["parent_id"]=>
    NULL
  }
}
```

But what I really want is just this

```
      object(stdClass)#422 (4) {
        ["name"]=>
        string(8) "Blah1"
        ["full_name"]=>
        string(9) "Blah1"
        ["id"]=>
        string(32) "BlahBlah2"
        ["parent_id"]=>
        NULL
      }
```

Then I have to do this to just get the actual object

```
$theKey = key($found_label);

return $found_label[$theKey];
```

I thought they should be a better way of doing this, also I'm new to PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that with array_filter, there is no way to stop it and return only the first result. If you can't use the key to extract the result you want from the array returned from array_filter, you should use a loop. Something like this:

```
$label = "wantedLabel";
foreach ($labels as $l) {
    if( $l->name === $label ) {
        print_r ($l);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<?php

$labels = array(
  "0" => (object) array('name' => "name1", "title" => "title1"),
   "1" => (object) array('name' => "name2", "title" => "title2")
);

$label = "name1";

$found_label = array_filter($labels, function($obj) use($label) {
   return $obj->name === $label;
});

print_r($found_label[0]);
```

Produces:

```
stdClass Object ( [name] => name1 [title] => title1 )
```